# How can you overcome the struggling during interview?

Tags: interviewing

What should you do you found faults answer of interviewer's question after interview end up?

Would you please let me know what if you have no idea for interviewer's question during interview?

Comment: You may want to look here and see if it answers your question: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18814/how-should-i-respond-to-interview-questions-when-i-dont-know-the-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for clarifications, listing the aspects of the question that are problematic and laying out why they are problematic. Follow up on the clarifications until you get to the point that you are comfortable giving a clear, definite answer. Alternatively, follow up with a clear, definite answer, laying out the assumptions you are making in generating your answer.

Think of people's minds as submarines. When you say that they are flat wrong, the reflex action is to get defensive. When they get defensive, their minds shut down, they batten the hatches and the submarine goes into a deep dive to get away from the depth charges. And they won't resurface until they are sure that the destroyers have left the area. In your case, the interviewer's mind won't resurface from its receptive mode until the interview is over and the candidate is gone. In this case, the interview is YOUR interview and the candidate is YOU, so it's going to suck to be you.

You can't count on someone's mind staying open when that someone is being told that they are wrong. I, like many users on this site, have conditioned to keep my mind open when I am told that I am wrong, but I am not everyone. Telling an interviewer that they are wrong is playing Russian roulette, and all you know about that revolver is that there is at least one bullet in it.